# Caching limited associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord

I'm trying to cache an ActiveRecord with its association. **The problem is there's a database query when accessing the associations on a retrieved record.**

Normally, I'd just cache with eager-loading `Rails.cache.write('post', Post.includes(:comments).find(99))`. This seems to work, but the problem is I only want to cache a limited subset of the association, and limits are ignored when eager-loading (mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/3d41450169e28c40/a8a68993ee8e7258) for example). So `Post.includes(:popular_comments).find(99)` would return *all* comments, not just the popular ones.

So I've tried caching the object after lazy-loading the association, but a query unfortunately occurs when pulling the objects out:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :popular_comments, :class_name > 'Comment', :limit => 20, :order => :votes

post = Post.find(99)
post.popular_comments # lazy-load limited associations
Rails.cache.write('post', post)
...
Rails.cache.read('post').popular_comments # Unwanted SQL query :(
```

I've tried caching a clone instead, same unwanted SQL query. And I've tried this with both redis and memcached implementations, same result. Oddly, this sequence does work on console afaict, but a simple usage in a controller or view like above fails (ie SQL occurs).

*Update (April 2017): I would now say this is a silly premise. Caching whole objects is generally wasteful as it uses a lot of cache storage and it's slow to serialise/deserialise them. Caching associations as well (as asked in this question) is multiplying that wastage by N. Usually it's more efficient to just cache raw IDs and HTML fragments.*

Comment: Which version of Rails are you running?

Comment: @Brandan This is on Rails 3.1

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the log showing exactly what SQL is getting executed and where in the request it's happening? I couldn't reproduce this.

Comment: @Brandan Don't have this exact code now, but I'll see if I can reproduce this with a dummy project.

Comment: What is your Rails versions? I tried this in my setup and it worked for me.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu 3.1. Could you post your code somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `post.popular_comments.reload`

First, limits are in fact ignored when eager loading. From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it will be ignored, returning all the associated objects

This means, like you discovered, you have to force the association into the parent object yourself. In my experiments, `post.popular_comments` didn't work (this makes sense, since it returns a proxy object), and interestingly neither did `post.popular_comments.all`. `post.popular_comments(true)` does the trick, however. Underneath that code calls reload, and simply doing `post.popular_comments.reload` also gets the association loaded into the parent class.

I'm not sure which of these two is more correct, `post.popular_comments(true)` or `post.popular_comments.reload`. Both seem a bit brittle, but the second one reads nicer and expresses your intent more clearly.

I validated that both these methods:

1. stored the limited association in memcache
2. did not trigger a SQL query after loading from cache

My script to store the post:

```
require 'pp'
Rails.cache.clear
post = Post.first

#post.popular_comments(true)
post.popular_comments.reload

Rails.logger.info "writing to cache"
s = Rails.cache.write "post", post
Rails.logger.info "writing to cache done"
```

And to retrieve:

```
require 'pp'
Rails.logger.info "reading from cache"
post = Rails.cache.read "post"
Rails.logger.info "reading from cache done"
Rails.logger.info post.popular_comments.inspect
```

If I run one after the other my log shows:

```
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` LIMIT 1
  Comment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`post_id` = 1 ORDER BY votes LIMIT 20
writing to cache
writing to cache done
reading from cache
reading from cache done
[#<Comment id: 1, ...
```

My mySQL log also confirms that the second script does not trigger a query for the association.

This was done with Rails 3.1.1

Comment: Great, answer, thanks. I can't test it right now, but you've understood the problem and this sounds like the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing the problem that you described in my tests.

Code that I have used in controller

```
def show
  unless Rails.cache.exist?('faq_category')
    @faq_category = Faq::Category.first
    @faq_category.questions
    Rails.cache.write('faq_category', @faq_category)
  end
  @faq_category = Rails.cache.read('faq_category')
end
```

When I run the page I see the following statements in log which says that the models are not getting reloaded
[image]
Larger image available at https://skitch.com/aroop/g9w5t/untitled

The problem could be with your view file. Comment the view and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: This is an issue I'm seeing where a has_many association is limited. I've put more info in the question.

Comment: I will try to simulate your situation when I get a moment

Comment: Many thanks. It shouldn't be that complicated. Just a has_many association with a limit defined on the association.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 doesn't support `:limit => 20` option at all. you will get below error:

> ArgumentError: Unknown key: :limit. Valid keys are: :class_name,
>   :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name,
>   :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend,
>   :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type,
>   :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type, :index_errors

You have to use `post.popular_comments.limit(20)` explicitly.